# Including images in comments: Is it fine to use imgur link in the comments?

Tags: support, comments, images

[Here, I wanted to post an image in the comment](https://superuser.com/a/734583/93604). I did a trick:

- I clicked on "Ask Question" here on Meta
- Then I clicked the icon "Add image"
- I uploaded the image from my computer and copied the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYoPR.png
- I pasted the link to the comment
- I discarded the question.

### Is this a clean and correct approach?

An example thought why this possibly wouldn't be clean: Is the image hosted permanently? There could be, in theory, some "garbage collector" that would delete all images that are not linked from within any question (well, mine is now linked from this question, though not normally - funny enough right :-)).

Comment: Images are hosted permanently; this works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Images uploaded using the post editor (you can use an answer post too) are hosted on the dedicated `i.stack.imgur.com` host.

These images remain there permanently, there is no garbage collector like on regular `imgur.com` images (which get deleted [after 6 months with no views](https://imgur.com/faq#long)).

Quoting the [original blog post announcing the hosting change](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/):

> Alan Schaaf, the man behind Imgur, generously provided us a network-wide “pro” account that **keeps any images hosted through our websites around indefinitely**.

I do exactly the same thing if I need to include an image in a comment.

Note that comments are very much seen as impermanent; we don't really care all that much if those image links *in comments* got lost. Put any information that is important *in the post itself*, not in a comment.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, perfect information.

Comment: I wasn't aware of their deletion policy, I frequently upload using imgur.com instead of going through the editor :\

Comment: @Stijn: search for such images with `user:me url:"i.imgur.com/*"` and re-upload them with the editor (just copy and paste the `imgur.com` url in to the form).

Comment: @Stijn: That won't find comments, of course; you would have to use a [Data explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com) instead for that. But comments are not meant to be permanent anyway.