# Are the images from deleted posts kept?

Tags: discussion, imgur, deleted-posts

What happens to the images from deleted questions and/or answers?

Will they be kept or they will be deleted with the answer?

What happens with the images, that are edited out from the post? The links are still there in revision history, but what with the image under that link?

Comment: Nothing is deleted, _ever_.

Comment: There have been hard deletions. But they are rare.

Comment: Related: [Including images in comments: Is it fine to use imgur link in the comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227089)

Comment: Interesting, learned something new today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general they're kept around, because – as Toon Krijthe [says correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229515/115866) – deletion isn't necessarily the end of it. In particular, posts can be undeleted.

Once in a while we *do* delete images if we need to (a few days ago, someone uploaded a photo of their credit card, for example), but that's fully manual, and usually in response to a moderator notifying us of a problematic image.

Comment: Another day, another chair. There goes my *never* assertion! :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters "In response to moderator notification" is, as far as I'm concerned, close enough to "never" (translation: kinda rare from my point of view).

Comment: @MartijnPieters [Could be worse](http://a.gifb.in/122010/1292522602_dog-pulls-womans-hair.gif).

Comment: Auwie! My hair is long enough; I see I'll have to watch my back now for a Balpha-shaped dog next time I assert anything!

Comment: In [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229514/are-the-images-from-deleted-posts-kept#comment753553_229516) the [URL](http://a.gifb.in/122010/1292522602_dog-pulls-womans-hair.gif) is missing, the new URL is: https://www.gifbin.com/984896

Answer (score 3):

Deleted posts are not hard deleted. Users with 10.000 reputation points can still see them. So the images are saved too.

The revision history is also kept.

Hard deletion of posts or revisions are rare.

Comment: And even then images are not deleted.

Comment: MartijnPieters So somewhere on the SE servers sits a lonely image of a boat...

Comment: It is forever waiting for a programmer. Except it was posted before the dedicated SE Imgur domain was added...

Answer (score 1):

As of July 2019, when a post is deleted through spam or offensive flags Stack Exchange sends automatic removal request to imgur for any image in that post.

[More details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378543/152859).