# Is it safe to reuse an image from an older post?

Tags: support, images, imgur

Suppose I made a post which contains an image (which I uploaded the usual way using the uploader in the editor). Many months later, I decide to make another post using the image from the earlier post. Is it safe to reuse an image that was previously uploaded as part of an older post? I don't want my new post to have broken images in the future.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+are+imgur+images+hosted+indefinitely) of [Will links to images be kept permanently when added to a comment and nothing else?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251881/289905) (also on [Math Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3272/530912)); [from the official blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/): _“[Imgur] generously provided us a network-wide ‘pro’ account that keeps any images hosted through our websites around **indefinitely**.”_ (emphasis mine). Doesn’t matter if comment or post.

Comment: There’s also this older post that I missed earlier — [Including images in comments: Is it fine to use imgur link in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227089/289905) — which the other question is a duplicate of. You can check out all the related questions in the “Linked” sidebar, too.

Comment: If you aren't sure, I don't think anyone would mind if you re-upload it